# SQL Query table with multiple records with matching columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL database with a table that has phone number records with a few fields

```
PersonGUID (Fk, uniqueidentifier)
PhoneSequence (int)
PhoneTypeCode (Fk)
AreaCode 
PhoneNumber
PhoneGUID (Pk, uniqueidentifier)
```

It's normal for there to be multiple records for each PersonGUID but we had an error when importing a bulk list of phone number records where the `PhoneSequence` was set as 1 for the same `PersonGUID` records.  These people have multiple records where `PhoneTypeCode='Mobile'` and `PhoneTypeCode='Home'` and both are marked with `PhoneSequence=1` so the system assumes they have two primary phone numbers.

I want to create a query that will search the table for anyone that has multiple records but cannot figure out how to say "find people that have both a home and mobile phone and both records' sequence is 1"

Inevitably, I'd like to update the Home phone records (for users that have both) so the sequence is 2.

This is the closest I've been able to figure out:

```
update tPersonPhone
set PhoneSequence = 2
from tPersonPhone pp
where PhoneTypeCode ='home' and
exists (select * from PersonPhone pp1 
        where pp.PersonPhoneGUID = pp1.PersonPhoneGUID 
        and PhoneTypeCode in ('home','mobile') 
        and PhoneSequence = 1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added tags, using MS SQL Server 08R2

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks a bit like SQL Server.  If so, you want something like this:

```
update pp
    set PhoneSequence = 2
from tPersonPhone pp
where pp.PhoneTypeCode = 'home' and pp.PhoneSequence = 1 and
exists (select 1
        from tPersonPhone pp2
        where pp2.PersonPhoneGUID = pp1.PersonPhoneGUID and
              pp2.PhoneTypeCode = 'mobile' and
              pp2.PhoneSequence = 1
       );
```

Most other databases have a similar syntax.  The basic logic is:  update the phone sequence to 2 when a home number has a sequence of 1 and there is a corresponding mobile number with a sequence of 1.